# error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token

Tags: c++, linux, porting

I am trying to compile some C++ code (which can be compiled with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows) with `g++-4.4`.

I have this snippet of code,

```
const std::string cnw::restoreSession(const std::vector<string> &inNwsFile) {
   for (std::string &nwFile : inNwsFile){
       // some...
   }
}
```

that I cannot compile because of this error:

```
CNWController.cpp:154: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

Can you give me some advise on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using a colon instead of a semi-colon in the for loop?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Because that's the syntax for C++11's range-based `for`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your compiler is too old to support range-based `for` syntax. According to [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) it was first supported in GCC 4.6. GCC also requires you to explicitly request C++11 support, by giving the command-line option `-std=c++11`, or `c++0x` on compilers as old as yours.

If you can't upgrade, then you'll need the old-school equivalent:

```
for (auto it = inNwsFile.begin(); it != inNwsFile.end(); ++it) {
    std::string const &nwFile = *it; // const needed because inNwsFile is const
    //some...
}
```

I believe `auto` is available in GCC 4.4 (as long as you enable C++0x support), to save you writing `std::vector<string>::const_iterator`.

If you really do need a non-`const` reference to the vector's elements then, whichever style of loop you use, you'll need to remove the `const` from the function parameter.

Comment: He might also need the `-std=C++11` flag when compiling.

Comment: @olevegard: Indeed, although it's a lower-case `c` and older compilers call it `c++0x`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked. Yes, I have to use `c++0x`, flag `c++11` is not supported by my compiler.